# Add Sub Total and Total in JS Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am loading a data from a data source which is already complex, once the data has loaded, I want to add total to in the bottom of each column. Once I add the total I want to add another set of value underneath this manually added total, so that I can multiply these both and show a final total.

FYI: [The JOB 1] Columns are sub property of the record (Object Array). I made them vertical via JS. So adding a sub total from the Server Side API in the end of the record is messy which I don't want to do.

**Q1:** how to add total of each row?

**Q2:** how can I add a second row of prices underneath it (These values are can be brought from the same API and map it accordingly for each column.)

**Q3:** Multiply both of these and show a final total?

[image]